# Filter MongoDB source dataset within copy activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: filtering, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline which uses a MongoDB JSON file as the source dataset and need to sink it into a SQL Database.

My problem is that the JSON file contains too many rows, so I am trying to only retrieve rows from the last *n* days.

Is it possible to filter a source dataset within the copy activity, so in other words without using the filter activity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can filter the source dataset within the copy activity.

You can ref the ticket: [Azure Data Factory - filter Mongodb source dataset by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58875709/azure-data-factory-filter-mongodb-source-dataset-by-date).

It has the same problem and the answer shows you how to filter the data with date.